# What is subject.invoke in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Accordingly to `rails 4.2.4` and `rspec 3.4` upgrading, I am fixing specs in large application. Previous developers used `subject.invoke`, but now seems like it doesn't work. What is `subject.invoke` and how I can substitute it?

Answer (score 2):

This will be really hard to answer this question for one specific reason - `subject` can be anything and it is defined in your test.

There are two ways `subject` can be defined - implicitly or explicitly. Implicitly, it uses a class used in a top-most `describe`, so if you have:

```
describe MyClass do
  it 'works' do
    subject
  end
end
```

`subject` will execute `MyClass.new` and will cache the result so every subsequent call to subject will return the same object.

You can override the default subject using explicit `subject` definition:

```
describe MyClass do
  subject { described_class.new some: "extra-params" }
  it 'works' do
    subject
  end
end
```

So, `subject.invoke` is jest executing `invoke` method on whatever object your subject is. You will need to find out what your `subject` is and find its class to get to the definition of `invoke`

Answer (score 0):

`subject` is the return value of the `subject` block in the current context. If you there is a block like this

```
subject { Foo.new }
```

then a `subject` call in the example would return the new `Foo` instance.

The following `invoke` is just calling `invoke` on the `subject`. Therefore it depends on the implementation of the subject.